# How long to wait until license modal stops appearing?

Tags: multi-environment, license

I recently setup a pre-production environment of my fully purchased Craft site license, but Craft license management didn't think the sub-domain I was using was "dev-sounding" enough. Now that I've rectified that problem by creating a sub-domain included on CraftCMS's official list and destroying the previous one, how long will I have to wait before my *production* instance stops complaining about needing a payment for trial licenses?

Answer (score 1):

Your production website shouldn't have been complaining about a different website using the same license key, as long as the license key is bound to the production websites domain name...

To get rid of the error, you can clear your Data caches. You can do this by navigating to **Utilities > Caches** in your Control Panel, and there you can unselect all but **Data caches**. Once you clicked **Clear Caches**, you reload the page and the message(s) will be gone.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The message persists on the production website. Also, the key is bound to the production website's domain name and has been up with no problems for over two years.